# Xbox Live chat bot example

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-live

Looking for any documentation about implementation of automated chat bot for Xbox Live or any ability to send and receive messages with help of api.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: Not sure that this service supports Xbox Live chat.